# Confusing PAD layout in datasheet

Tags: datasheet, mechanical, pad

I am planning to use a Right Angle RGB LED [EASV3015RGBA0](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjHqKjiq_PPAhXGEZAKHZdMBOQQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Feverlightamericas.com%2Findex.php%3Fcontroller%3Dattachment%26id_attachment%3D1129&usg=AFQjCNG_0K345h03rN6UNmxwKH_bre92cw&sig2=vdIB6qGitTDZEcRgjAZ7Hw&cad=rja) and here is the package dimension and recommended soldering pad:

[image: LED]

[image: LED pads]

Top matches with LED image(see the anode mark). Bottom is consistent with top. However in recommended soldering pattern, for the given LED orientation, I feel that pad sequence should be 4, 3, 2, 1 rather than 1, 2, 3, 4. Or alternatively, the LED will face in opposite direction (180 degrees rotated).

Am I correct or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the drawings into consideration, the conclusion would be that the "Bottom" view is flipped in relation to "Recommended soldering pad" (as you imagined). Which one is correct would be hard to determine.

Then, a few pages ahead:

[image]

Looking by this image, which details how the LED comes in the reel, we can get further evidence that the "recommended" soldering pad is the one mirrored. As Anonymous said: contact the manufacturer to be sure.

I was looking at another datasheet now, and in this other one ([EASV3020RGA1](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ-LzurPPPAhUCx5AKHc9OAGgQFggzMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Feverlightamericas.com%2Findex.php%3Fcontroller%3Dattachment%26id_attachment%3D1140&usg=AFQjCNFGwK2-MJZXIRErIB_InIqyqnr0-A&sig2=_zGm4YdmWkrU4YKOyWvNlQ)) the pin numbering in the Pads is "reversed" in relation to the one you posted (that is, not conflicting with the other drawings in the .pdf):

[image]

So.. again, nothing definitive, but many things pointing to an actual error in the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems like the recommended soldering pad is mirrored because top, bottom and the reel diagram are consistent among themselves. I did this simple test to clear my visualization doubts. Took a paper, wrote 1,2,3,4 and TOP on one side. Flipped it over. Wrote the pin numberings and BOTTOM on the flipped side. Now this paper matches with the reel diagram but not with the recommended solder pattern.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack -- there are actually 3D files (steps and igs) on their website, which I thought would help with the 3D visualization, but none of those have the pads in them, just the general dimensions. So they're useless in our case.

Comment: Without pads, yeah it's useless for us. Well I looked at other LEDs by everlight which strongly suggest that recommended layout is mirrored. Take a look at this one: http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/201407052004528767.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the drawings are, at best, confusing. [Wesley Lee's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/265325/53747) has gone into that in detail.

In addition to the package drawings, it does not help that the product drawing in the datasheet:
[image: product drawing from datasheet]

differs from the image provided on the [Everlight Americas website](https://everlightamericas.com/pcb/1336/easv3015rgba0.html) in small, but significant ways (e.g. metal areas, clarity of anode/pin 1 mark, physical shape of corners, etc.):
[image: product image from website]

### Contact the manufacturer:

When in doubt, [contact the manufacturer](https://everlightamericas.com/contact-us) and ask. A phone call will probably result in a more rapid response. When you do so, please suggest that they update their datasheet. They *might* actually update it, which would help the people trying to use the part in the future.

### Get a sample. Physically verify:

If still in doubt, **get a sample**.  Physically verify that what you believe is true, the physical pinout, is actually true.

You can either get a sample from the manufacturer, or order one from a supplier. The manufacturer should be able to rapidly provide a sample. A manufacturer's willingness to provide free sample parts may depend on the manufacturer's policies, the actual part desired, the quantity of samples you request, your relationship with the manufacturer, your projected volume, the size of your company, etc. In some cases, I've offered to pay for expedited/overnight shipping on samples. If you are unable to get samples from the manufacturer, then, hopefully, you will be able to find a supplier that stocks the part (ask the manufacturer if there are any stocking suppliers).

In this case, the [Everlight Americas website](https://everlightamericas.com/pcb/1336/easv3015rgba0.html) allows you to place an order for a limited quantity of this part, EASV3015RGBA0, directly from the manufacturer (100 in stock) for a per unit price of $0.14. You have the option of selecting shipping speeds up to FedEx Standard Overnight.

When in doubt, the cost of getting a sample is *way* below having to turn a board due to an error in layout.  How much you should be willing to spend for the sample, and for increasing the speed of shipping, will be a trade-off vs. the cost of any delay which might be caused.

Personally, given both the ease of ordering the part from the manufacturer and its low cost, I would just go ahead and order some sample parts so I could physically verify this myself. Being 100% sure by physically verifying the pinout would have more value to me than the cost of having the parts shipped. Depending on the time of day, I would place the order even prior to contacting the manufacturer, but not instead of contacting them (i.e. do both, but place the order such that it could go out the same day, if possible).

### If you *still* can not resolve the ambiguity:

You should *seriously* consider using another part. The inability to get sample parts is an indicator that you may have problems sourcing this part in manufacturing. Using a different part, with similar functionality, which is more readily available, may be a significantly better choice.

Look closely at why you are not able to resolve this issue. While there might be some valid reasons, I'm having a hard time coming up with some good ones off the top of my head. For other parts and other problems, there might be good reasons. But, for this part and this problem...hard to come up with a good enough reason that does not say to me "don't use this part".

If you are *really* going to use this part, and still have ambiguity as to the physical pinout, you can design the board to handle both possibilities. This can be handled in multiple ways. A couple of common methods are:

- Have two land patterns, both connected. This assumes that the physical position on the board is not critical and you have the space on the board.
- Route the signals appropriately to a single physical location while accommodating either pinout. In this case, the issue is pinout, not the physical size/position of the pins. Thus, you can allow for the possibility of either pinout in your design. For example, zero ohm resistors which are populated, or not, depending on the physical pinout. Alternately, you could use traces that are cut. What method you choose, of the multiple possible ways you could do this, will depend on your manufacturing process and how you are driving these pins (e.g. for the pin 2 & 3 swap it might be done in software). However, almost all solutions will increase cost.

What solution is appropriate, if any, will depend on multiple factors (e.g. stage in prototype➞manufacturing, expected volume for this run of the board, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

<s>*Bottom* is the view from the bottom as you look at it, soldering pad pattern is view from the top onto the place where bottom is put. Thus it is mirrored view of the bottom.</s>

If you take bottom view and flip it around horizontal axis you will get soldering pattern.

**Edit:** while my answer above may generally apply, there's really something wrong within the drawing.

It seems for me that LED can be mounted vertically and with its side. If mounted vertically, it is soldered using its "notched" contacts at its sides if you look from the top, if with side then using LED's "bottom" contacts.

But what you found out is that if putting LED in the direction as it is shown at the right you get left pad connecting to pin 2 and right pad connecting to pin 3.

Thus I would say there seems to be a mistake in it, LED should look downwards rather than upwards on "recommend soldering pad" drawing.

If you will look further the datasheet, it says

> Suggested pad dimension is just for reference only. Please modify the pad dimension based on individual need.

Please contact manufacturer for clarifications. If it is drawing mistake, they should thank you because if people will read it wrongly they will have their devices not working or even fried, and blame product for issues.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is Right angle mounted LED, so LED doesn't sit on the bottom face. Instead it will sit on one side. Does that change your answer? Sorry for not mentioning it earlier in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I modified my answer. I think datasheet is scarce on the information on the device and its mounting methods.

Comment: I tried reaching out to them through their contact us page. I feel lucky that I noticed it right before sending my PCBs for fabrication.